# no recibo json en php

Tags: php, json, login

Tengo el problema que me están enviando desde una app móvil un *json* con los datos (usuario y contraseña) por medio de *POST*.

El problema es que no he podido encontrar la manera de recibirlo.
Anteriormente usaba esto y me funcionaba:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

pero al imprimir me regresa un null

Luego probe con:

```
$usuario= $_REQUEST['email'];
$password= $_REQUEST['password'];
$pasword = hash('sha512', $password);
```

solo para comprobar si llega el string del metodo GET y verifiqué que los datos si llegan.

Comment: Debes agregar el código que envia esos datos, pues el problema podría estar allí, y así también veremos que métodos usan para enviar los datos. Por otra parte, prueba con `print_r($_REQUEST);` a ver si recibes algo desde la app, pues si es así entonces es que han cambiado el método para mandarlos y en este caso, si te sale algo, es probable que los esten enviando por POST.

Comment: hola, gracias por responder, en la pregunta que realize coloque que los datos me los estan mandando por POST  el código de la app no lo tengo,  pero pedi que me mandaran datos de prueba por GET y como es natural llegaron sin problema, pero JSON no se como recibirlo,  pues por falta uso no recuerdo como hacerlo

Comment: Las dos formas que has puesto en la pregunta parecen correctas para recibir los datos, es decir, que si te los estan enviando por POST los deberias poder ver o bien en una o en otra.  Si ninguna te funciona entonces más bien parece un error por la parte del que lo envia, no tuya.  Si te estan mandando un objeto debes poderlo recibirlo con `php:///input`, y si te estan enviando datos procesados deberías poderlos ver con un `print_r($_REQUEST);`.  Si no recibes nada entonces es cuando aparece lo del **null** supongo.

Comment: prueba usar ngrep si estas en linux o Wireshark para windows y asi detectar claramente que tipo de peticion http esta haciendo cuando la app envia los datos, tambien podras ver los datos enviados.

Comment: encontre el problema gracias por tu aporte

Comment: Si has encontrado el problema y la solución estaría bien que lo compartieras con la comunidad posteando una respuesta, siguiendo las normas de [answer], y en 48 horas la podrás aceptar para darle más visibilidad y para que la pregunta no quede pendiente eternamente, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

gracias a los comentarios de masterguru y John encontre que el problema estaba del lado del envio de datos, por medio de GET llegaban datos pero por medio de POST llegaban en NULL, enviamos el informa y el otro equipo que envia los datos pudo corregir, cuando se trabajan tareas por equipos y hay un problema, la colaboración es importante para no perder tiempo.

Comment: No olvides aceptar tu respuesta.